# How pass in ruby on rails an argument from form to jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have next form:

```
.well
  = form_for @message, data: { chanell: @chanell }, remote: true do |f|
    .form-group
      = f.label :body, "Enter your message:"
      = f.text_area :body, rows: 3, class: 'form-control', required: true, maxlength: 2000
      %small.label.label-warning Cannot be blank or contain more than 2000 symbols.
      = hidden_field_tag 'chanell', @chanell

    = f.submit 'Send', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'
```

How do i pass **chanell** to method **client.publish** in file **/messages/create.js.rb**

```
publisher = client.publish("<% params[:chanell] %>", {
  message: "<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => @message, :layout => false))%>"
});

publisher.callback(function() {
  $('#message_body').val('');
  $('#new_message').find("input[type='submit']").val('Submit').prop('disabled', false)
});

publisher.errback(function() {
  alert('There was an error while posting your message.');

});
```

Comment: is it `HAML` format you using Stefan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
publisher = client.publish("<%= params[:chanell] %>", {
  message: "<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => @message, :layout => false))%>"
});
```

you were missing `=` sign;